# numpy array of array vs numpy array of list

Tags: python, numpy

i have this two numpy arrays

```
arr1 = np.empty( (3,) , dtype=np.object)
arr1[0] = [1,2]
arr1[1] = [1,2,3]
arr1[2] = None
```

```
arr2 = np.empty( (3,) , dtype=np.object)
arr2[0] = np.array([1,2])
arr2[1] = np.array([1,2,3])
arr2[2] = None
```

why , when i'm checking if the internal array/list is None i'm getting different results
both have the same shape

```
In [28]: arr1 != None
Out[28]: array([ True,  True,  False])
```

```
In [27]: arr2 != None
Out[27]: True
```

what is the way in numpy to check, that each element in arr2 is None?

Comment: as an aside, just use `object`, `np.object` is just `object`

Comment: This is happening because one of the elementwise comparisons failed, because using `==` on an `np.ndarray` will throw an error.

Comment: Also note, you probably shouldn't be using *either* of these arrays... an `object` dtype array is just a less performant `list`

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[a is not None for a in arr2]`.  Your arrays contain `None` in addition to lists and arrays.  Expecting the same behavior for different classes of objects is unrealistic in python.  Also most operations on object dtype arrays occur at list-comprehension speeds; so don't jump through hoops trying to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the line `arr2 != None` raises the following DeprecationWarning on newer versions of Numpy:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

The reason is that `my_array != my_object` calls `my_array[i] != my_object` for each `i`, and expects to get back a boolean value at each element. Instead though, it gets back `array([ False, False])` as the first element (not just a boolean).

So essentially, the difference is that `list != None` returns False, but `numpy_array_of_ints != None` returns an array. Elementwise comparisons should only return an array of booleans.

Edit: looking at [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.not_equal.html),
the return value of elementwise comparisons are "Typically of type bool, unless dtype=object is passed." As such, we can do this:

```py
>>> np.not_equal(arr1, None, dtype=object)
array([True, True, False], dtype=object)
>>> np.not_equal(arr2, None, dtype=object)
array([array([ True,  True]), array([ True,  True,  True]), False],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: 10x  @Dennis , starting to get it. but that still have different results 
np.not_equal(arr2, None, dtype=object) , result are for each  int element
while i'm trying to get the result of each arr[int] element like in the case of arr1

Comment: As other users suggested, I would just do [x is not None for x in arr2] to get a list. In fact, I would just make arr2 be a list in the first place--NumPy arrays really only shine when storing scalar values, but standard python lists are better for storing python objects.